# Using java and regex to remove comma and a new line but having problems

Tags: java, regex

I wrote a little demo method to try and solve this issue. I am writing some DDL statements from inspecting a database, but i cannot execute these statements because I have an extra comma at the end of each section:

I want my data to look like this:

```
ALTER TABLE my_evolv.account_type 
    ADD CONSTRAINT FOREIGN KEY (account_type_id) REFERENCES account_type (account_type_id)ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE,
    ADD CONSTRAINT FOREIGN KEY (update_log_id) REFERENCES update_log (update_log_id)ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE

ALTER TABLE my_evolv.actions_library 
    ADD CONSTRAINT FOREIGN KEY (actions_library_id) REFERENCES actions_library (actions_library_id)ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE,
    ADD CONSTRAINT FOREIGN KEY (update_log_id) REFERENCES update_log (update_log_id)ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE

ALTER TABLE my_evolv.actions_library_parameters
```

and so on. This is my code:

```
private static void removeComma(){

    String row1 =       
        "ALTER TABLE my_evolv.account_type \n"+
        "   ADD CONSTRAINT FOREIGN KEY (account_type_id) REFERENCES account_type (account_type_id)ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE,\n"+
        "   ADD CONSTRAINT FOREIGN KEY (update_log_id) REFERENCES update_log (update_log_id)ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE,\n";
    String row2 = 
        "ALTER TABLE my_evolv.actions_library \n"+
        "   ADD CONSTRAINT FOREIGN KEY (actions_library_id) REFERENCES actions_library (actions_library_id)ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE,\n"+
        "   ADD CONSTRAINT FOREIGN KEY (update_log_id) REFERENCES update_log (update_log_id)ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE,\n";
    String row3 = 
        "ALTER TABLE my_evolv.actions_library_parameters ";     

    StringBuilder s = new StringBuilder();
    s.append(row1);
    String newVal = s.toString();
    newVal.replaceAll("(,\nALTER)", "\nALTER");
    System.out.println("row1:"+ newVal.toString());
    s = new StringBuilder(newVal);


    s.append(row2);
    newVal = s.toString();
    newVal.replaceAll("(,\nALTER)", "\nALTER");
    System.out.println("row2:"+ newVal.toString());
    s = new StringBuilder(newVal);

    s.append(row3);
    newVal = s.toString();
    newVal.replaceAll("(,\nALTER)", "\nALTER");
    System.out.println("row3:"+ newVal.toString());
    s = new StringBuilder(newVal);

}
```

Comment: Format your question properly.

Comment: Yes I am new to this site... what is wrong with the format I used?

Comment: Thank you for the editing tips ArcaneCraeda, that is nicer to look at.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have commas anywhere but at the end of the Strings then following will do the trick

```
newVal = newVal.replaceAll(",", "");
```

This will replace all the commas in the String.

Also, If you really want to use StringBuilder to generate final String, use:

```
StringBuilder s = new StringBuilder((row1+row2).replaceAll(",", ""));
s.toString()
```

This is much cleaner.

Comment: is there a way to do it using regex?

Comment: more specifically I would like it to use REGEX to find the pattern of: ",[newline]ALTER" or ",[newline][newline]ALTER"

Comment: Signature of replaceAll function is,'String replaceAll(String regex, String replacement). Please keep in mind that it returns a String.

Comment: Yeah that is an important detail I missed... was I performing the check right then? Would String x = newVal.replaceAll("(,\nALTER)", "\nALTER"); find all , newline ALTER statements?

Comment: Yes, that should work. Why not you give it a try and compare the outputs to see, if that is something you want.

Answer (score 0):

You can fix this issue with help of following regex:

```
,\s+$
```

Code:

```
String row1 =
        "ALTER TABLE my_evolv.account_type \n"+
                "   ADD CONSTRAINT FOREIGN KEY (account_type_id) REFERENCES account_type (account_type_id)ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE,\n"+
                "   ADD CONSTRAINT FOREIGN KEY (update_log_id) REFERENCES update_log (update_log_id)ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE,\n";

String regex = ",\\s+$";

// Create a Pattern object
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regex);
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(row1);

String result = matcher.replaceAll("");

System.out.println(result);
```

It will print:

```
ALTER TABLE my_evolv.account_type 
   ADD CONSTRAINT FOREIGN KEY (account_type_id) REFERENCES account_type (account_type_id)ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE,
   ADD CONSTRAINT FOREIGN KEY (update_log_id) REFERENCES update_log (update_log_id)ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
```

As you can see it has removed last comma.